# Is it possible to block any application in android

Tags: android

I have to implement functionality in which I can block any application installed in device by filling password.
When I click on icon for start application then it should ask for password.
Is it possible. Please give suggestion about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> block any application installed in device

You can achieve this by modifying the firmware.

> When I click on icon for start application then it should ask for password

It is also possible if you have INSTALL_SHORTCUT and UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT permission. Then you will be able to do what a Launcher can do. Take [this link](http://maketecheasier.com/create-shortcuts-to-any-applications-in-android/2010/10/14) as an example.

Comment: I need to add that on some devices it might be also possible using Exchange policies without any change froms firmware (user just need to have exchange account enabled on the phone and accepted device administrator request from Mail app).

Answer (score 3):

In Android this kind of beahaviour is not possible at applicaiton level.

Though i have an hack approach ,you can give it a try as follows:

Steps: Create a service which will continuously check for the running app on top stack :

You can check the current Application(any application) package name running at the top using the following code:

`String packageName= getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE).getRunningTasks(1).get(0)).topActivity.getPackageName();`

Now you need to compare the package name of the top running app that whether this is the app which you want to block..

**Suppose that you want to block the browser application in Android then when the user taps on the browser icon that app will move to top of the stack and your running service would recognize it.**

Then you need to open your own Dummy Lock screen over that applicaiton. In this way user will not be able to access that application and if the user tries to press the back button on your dummy lock screen then you need to override the back press and launch the Home Screen intent on it.

This is kind of a hack to create a applicaiton which can lock specific apps:
I have reverse engineered couple of apps from Play store and they also use this technique to perform this operation.

Hope this gives you an Idea .

Answer (score 1):

As Android is open source anything is possible but that means that you would have to rewrite Android OS natural behavior.

And to install this "hacked" OS on your device.
I dont see how you can provide this kind of service as an application.